# What is the connection between Legendre Symbols and Partitioning the Plane by Zig-Zags

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-number-theory

I found something a little weird today,

It appears that the prime factors of EVERY number in this sequence: [Which is the maximal number of ways to divide the plane using N zig-zags](http://oeis.org/A117625?fbclid=IwAR1NHa-tGggzp2gsESXtQ74FOJFZuDuFz_nv31iSU3diHNyzoROsOibZ0rA)

Are members of this sequence with a purely algebraic definition: [Primes whose 23 legendre symbol is 0 or 1](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+3%2C+13%2C+23%2C+29%2C+31%2C+41%2C+47%2C+59%2C+71%2C+73%2C&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

I wanted to prove this.

### My ideas:

The first sequence can be described by the formula $a(n) = 4.5n^2 - 3.5n + 1$. So we are trying to prove that the only prime factors of an integer of the form $\frac{9}{2} n^2 - \frac{7}{2} n  +1$ will have our desired legendre symbol criterion.

A partial result might be to try to prove:
  $$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{9}{2} n^2 - \frac{7}{2} n  +1 \\ p  \end{pmatrix}  = 1 \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} -23 \\ p  \end{pmatrix}  = 1     $$

Since that would imply that the products of the prime factors of our number multiply to (1), [So all factors with legendre symbol -1, must have even exponent]

Comment: Let $m = 18n - 7$. Then

$$2^3 \cdot 3^2 \left(\frac{9}{2} n^2 - \frac{7}{2} n + 1\right) = m^2 + 23.$$ 

So if $p > 3$ divides your expression, it divides $m^2 + 23$, and then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$9 x^2 - 7 x + 2 = 9 (x - 7/18)^2 + 23/36$$
Thus if $p$ is a prime $> 3$, the following are equivalent:

1. There is an integer $n$ such that $p \mid 9 n^2 - 7 n + 2$
2. $9 x^2 - 7 x + 2 = 0$ has a solution in the integers mod $p$
3. $-23$ is a square mod $p$.

EDIT: To see that (3) implies (2) and (1), suppose $-23 \equiv t^2 \mod p$.  Take $x \equiv 18^{-1} (t+7) \mod p$.  Then $9 x^2 - 7 x + 2 \equiv 9 (x - 7/18)^2 + 23/36
\equiv t^2/36 + 23/36 \equiv 0 \mod p$.

Comment: This answer isn't very clear to me,  I understand how [1.] implies [3.] but only because of (user860870's comment under neath my question). Can you explain how (3) implies (2) and how (2) implies (1)? then it'll be clear why these are all equivalent